# When setting loop, what does ";" do at the end of the closing bracket before function bracket

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and coding in general. I believe ";" is used to end a set of instructions, from what I've been reading.

For example:

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1);
```

When using `echo $variable` - it outputs 11, which is the 10 + 1.

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1)
```

When using `echo $variable` - it outputs all the numbers between 0 and 10.

Why does this happen with the addition of the semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1);
    echo $variable;
```

Is equivalent to

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1) {
    //do nothing
}
echo $variable;
```

Whereas this

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1)
    echo $variable;
```

Is equivalent to

```
for ($variable = 0; $variable <=10; $variable = $variable + 1) {
    echo $variable;
}
```

Both times, you are doing the stuff between the braces 11 times.  In the first instance, there is nothing between the braces, so AFTER the loop has completed, you are echoing the variable.

You get 11 because it increments the variable, then checks if it is less than or equal to 10.  It's not, so it goes to the next line, and output the variable.

In the other loop, you get 0 through 10 because each time it checks, and when it is 11, it does not enter the loop, and there is no longer an echo outside of the loop.

As a sidenote, it is good form to ALWAYS use braces, as it makes it much clearer what is going on.